# If all 9 strings in list is replaced: do something

Tags: python, list

As the title:
If all 9 strings in list is replaced, then a task should run.

Here is the code:

```
list = [
        ['0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0']
    ]
```

If all of them is either replaced by a "1" or "2" doesnt matter which is replaced by what. Then it should run a task.

So how do I if all of the 9 spots have been replaced by either a "1" or "2"?

There is simply too many possibilities to write all the combinations down, and compare them to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this,

```
s = set(item for sublist in lists for item in sublist)  # flat a list of lists into a set

if '0' not in s:
    do_something()
```

Comment: `if not '0' in s: ...`

Comment: I don't think you need len(s) ==1 since it could be more than that.

Comment: @joelgoldstick, thx for ur kind reminder. Yeah, `s` could be `{'1', '2'}`.

Comment: @sparkandshine
first line in your code, confused me a little, it worked though.. it's not wrong, it just confused me.
Could u please break it down for me?

This is how I understand it: For every string (item) in the list sublist, IN the list. For each of these (9) items  in "sublist" <-- ? what ? sublist again?

Didnt we already say it was in the sublist. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sparkandshine:  You don't need the brackets, a generator expression is fine: `s = set(item for sublist in lists for item in sublist)`

Comment: @sebastian is the list comprehension way of writing a double for-loop to add all the elements in the sublist inside the list into a set.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, many thanks. I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve it using `set()` and `itertools.chain()` function as:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain(*my_list)).issubset('12')
#     ^    ^          ^ all items in set are either '1' or '2'
#     ^    ^ creates a single list comprising the sub-list
#     ^  uniques values in the chained list
```

where `my_list` is your nested list.

*Note:* Do not use `list` as variable type because `list` is the built-in keyword denoting the `list` data-type in Python.

Sample run:

```
# Sample function
>>> def check_list(my_list):
...     return set(chain(*my_list)).issubset('12')
...

# Test Run:
>>> check_list([['0', '0'], ['0', '0']])
False
>>> check_list([['0', '1'], ['0', '0']])
False
>>> check_list([['1', '1'], ['1', '1']])
True
>>> check_list([['1', '2'], ['1', '2']])
True
```

Comment: `set(chain(*mylist)).issubset('12')`.  I think you need to test for 1 or 2. OP says "all of the 9 spots have been replaced by either a "1" or "2""

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Yes, I didn't saw the *'1' or '2'* part. In that case sub-set is the better choice. Updated the answer

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this `all(i!='0' for i in set(chain(*my_list)))` is equivalent to `'0' not in set(chain(*my_list))`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm no longer sure the OP worded his intentions correctly.  I now think he's fine with saying no zeros.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Thanks for reminding be about `'0' not in set()` part. It is been a long since I used it, and I totally forgot about this

Answer (score 0):

Never name a variable a reserved word, i.e. `list`. But here is an easy way.

```
l = [
        ['0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0']
    ]
if all(all(int(x) for x in row) for row in l):
   #do something
```

Comment: Nice, was typing up the same answer with `all()` but maybe you could define what `all()` does or point OP to the docs?

Comment: this won't work for strings containing a 0, like in the example, and is plain wrong in Python. Please, fix.

Comment: Oh, sorry just noticed they were strings. Is making them `int`s a possibility?

Comment: I edited it to convert to integers, as long as your initially condition of them being 0,1, or 2 is true, then it will work.

Comment: You can ut any expression to the right of the `for` command in a comprehension - but it won't work this way also.

I suggest a fast explanation about `for` and programing to the OP, since he did consider actually writting down a series of `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

To check if they have been replaced by `'1'` or `'2'` and nothing else

```
all(all(i in ('1', '2') for i in sublist) for sublist in list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question is how to I check to see if all sublists contain only `'1'` and `'2'`?

```
>>> mylist = [list('121'),list('111'), list('222')]
>>> mylist
[['1', '2', '1'], ['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
>>> all(item in ('1', '2') for sublist in mylist for item in sublist)
True
>>> mylist[0][0] = '0'
>>> mylist
[['0', '2', '1'], ['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
>>> all(item in ('1', '2') for sublist in mylist for item in sublist)
False
```